# Iterator for looping over ranges of parameters in subsets of dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, grid-search

I am trying to write a function that allows me to flexibly run grid searches over subsets of parameters in a dictionary. The specific behavior I am trying to accomplish is the following:

```
def my_grid_searching_function(fiducial_dict, **param_iterators):
    for params in desired_iterator:
        fiducial_dict.update(params)
        # compute chi^2
        # write new fiducial_dict values and associated chi^2 value to disk
```

**My specific goal is to figure out how to write `desired_iterator`.**

The function `my_grid_searching_function` accepts any arbitrary subset of keyword arguments, each of which will be interpreted as parameters of `fiducial_dict`.

This seems like a task for `itertools.product`, but I have run into a problem. In the following implementation, I am able to transform the nested loop over the *values* of the input iterators effectively into a single loop using `product`:

```
from itertools import product
def my_failed_grid_searching_function(fiducial_dict, **param_iterators):
    desired_iterator = product(*list(param_iterators.values()))
    for params in desired_iterator:
        print(params)
fiducial_dict = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 9}
my_failed_grid_searching_function(fiducial_dict, x=[4, 5, 6], y=[1, 2])    

(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
```

Of course the problem with this is that the input `param_iterators` have been splat into an ordinary dictionary, and so within the namespace of `my_failed_grid_searching_function` I do not know what the order of the values is.

Can anyone offer any tips on how I can write `desired_iterator` so that it yields sufficient information to update the `fiducial_dict` as shown above?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Scratch'N'Purr for pointing out that the sequence order can simply be determined from the .keys() method.

```
from itertools import product
def param_grid_search_generator(**param_iterators):
    param_names = list(param_iterators.keys())
    param_combination_generator = product(*list(param_iterators.values()))
    for param_combination in param_combination_generator:
        yield {param_names[i]: param_combination[i] for i in range(len(param_names))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using arbitrary keyword arguments, you could grab the keys of the `param_iterators` dictionary to sync up the position of your param product. Alternatively, I would recommend using the sklearn package to perform the [grid search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

Anyways, try this solution:

```
from itertools import product

def my_grid_searching_function(fiducial_dict, **param_iterators):
    keys = param_iterators.keys()
    desired_iterator = list(product(*list(param_iterators.values())))
    for i in range(len(desired_iterator)):
        print("Epoch: ", i)
        for loc in range(len(desired_iterator[i])):
            print(keys[loc], desired_iterator[i][loc])
        # update your fiducial_dict here

my_grid_searching_function({'x': 0, 'y': 0}, x=[1,2,3,4], y=[6,7,8])
```

Output:

```
('Epoch: ', 0)
('y', 6)
('x', 1)
('Epoch: ', 1)
('y', 6)
('x', 2)
('Epoch: ', 2)
('y', 6)
('x', 3)
('Epoch: ', 3)
('y', 6)
('x', 4)
('Epoch: ', 4)
('y', 7)
('x', 1)
('Epoch: ', 5)
('y', 7)
('x', 2)
('Epoch: ', 6)
('y', 7)
('x', 3)
('Epoch: ', 7)
('y', 7)
('x', 4)
('Epoch: ', 8)
('y', 8)
('x', 1)
('Epoch: ', 9)
('y', 8)
('x', 2)
('Epoch: ', 10)
('y', 8)
('x', 3)
('Epoch: ', 11)
('y', 8)
('x', 4)

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: Thanks @Scratch'N'Purr. Your first comment is most helpful - this was the pointer I needed to solve the problem I was trying to solve, so you deserve significant credit for the solution I'll post. The shortcoming of your proposed solution is that it requires allocating all the memory at once, so it's not really an iterator solution. Also, while sklearn grid_search is *highly* useful when exploring sklearn models, it is usable only for sklearn models, and I'd like to avoid having to transform every problem I work on into a sklearn-compatible model just to do a simple grid search.

Comment: No problem @aph! I notice you using the yield statement with the generator so it looks like you have the memory issue solved :)